# React changing style of NavBar on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm practicing some React here. I'd like my `NavBar` to get a `backgroundColor` past a certain scroll point which I've done, but when I scroll back to the top the `backgroundColor` does not change back to none. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
const top = {backgroundColor: 'none'}
const scrolled = {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'}


class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {style: top};

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = e => {

    if (window.scrollY < 200) {
      this.setState({style: top})
    } else if (window.scrollY > 200) {
      this.setState({style: scrolled})
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className='navBarContainer'>
        <nav className = 'navBar' onScroll={this.handleScroll} style={this.state.style}>
            <a className='navItem home' href='#'>SAINT<br />BARLEY<br />ROASTING</a>
            <a className='navItem shop' href='#'>shop</a>
            <a className='navItem blog' href='#'>blog</a>
            <a className='navItem bio' href='#'>bio</a> 
        </nav>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the "onScroll" event listener? That's not needed if you're going to add a window event listener in your lifecycle methods. Maybe they are competing?

Comment: Ok thanks. Just removed that. Still same result though :(

Comment: I thought you had already tried the "transparent" background fix, with no luck...  I would recommend using "initial" vs transparent if you want to reset a style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`none` is invalid for `backgroundColor`.

try `const top = {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}` instead.

Comment: I changed it to 'transparent' (and even 'red'). They both work but when I scroll back up, the style is stuck in the scrolled state.

Comment: have you tried `console.log(window.scrollY)` in your `handleScroll` function? does it return the right value? i've tested on my react build and it works perfectly

Comment: Yes it's returning the right values. So your backgroundColor goes back to transparent when scrolling back to the top?

Comment: @zheng is correct. I had interested this as well and then make a test on codesandbox according to zheng's answer. It works.[![Edit stackoverflow-59259027](https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg)](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-satoshi-xtmi1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: yes. that's correct. maybe try logging the state alongside the scrollY and see if that's behaving correctly.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks @Zheng